# Element API and Shopify plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-elementapi

Is there any way to translate this:

```
{% set shopify = craft.shopify.getProductById({ id: entry.shopifyProduct, fields: 'variants, id' }) %}
```

to the Element API?

I've tried this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
return [
  'endpoints' => [
  'api.json' => [
  'elementType' => 'Entry',
  'criteria' => [
    'section' => product,
  ],
  'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
    $shopify = craft()->shopify->getProductById({id:$entry->shopifyProduct});

    return [
      'id' => $entry->id,
      'title' => $entry->title,
      'url' => $entry->url,
      'shopifyId' => $entry->$shopify
    ];
  },
]
 ]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your PHP syntax – I didn't test this (not sure how the data model returned by `craft()->shopify->getProductById()` looks, and you'll need to verify that `$entry->shopifyProduct` returns a Shopify product ID), but at least the syntax errors should be fixed:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'product',
            ],
            'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
                $shopify = craft()->shopify->getProductById([ 'id' => $entry->shopifyProduct ]);
                return [
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'shopifyId' => $shopify ? $shopify->id : null,
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

With version 3.0 of the Shopify plugin (designed for Craft 4), products are now synchronized into Craft as elements, so you can make them available via Element API (with the native Shopify data *and* any custom fields you’ve added in Craft)!

We’ve provided [an example](https://github.com/craftcms/shopify#element-api) of working with the Element API in the documentation.